# Retornar Resultado de um IF executado pelo Prompt de Comando(CMD) em C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, cmd, return, prompt

Olá,
Estou tentando receber um retorno de uma linha IF do Prompt de Comando(CMD) com o Visual Studio 2015 em C#, mas não estou conseguindo.

O Código a seguir, executa o CMD, insere o caminho do diretório que contem um arquivo C++ (.cpp) e usando o compilador MinGW, compila e gera o executável (.exe) ou ocorre mensagem de erro. Utilizando o IF EXIST, confirmo se o executável foi criado ou não.
Mas o retorno do IF que indica se o arquivo foi encontrado (found) ou não (not found), não conseguindo fazer o retorno do resultado na qual, será usado em uma variável que futuramente servirá de validação.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnExecutar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string aspasDuplas = lblAspasDuplas.Text;
            string retornar;

            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // Não mostrar janela do cmd        

            Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"g++ -o Source Source.cpp");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"IF EXIST " + aspasDuplas + "Source.exe" + aspasDuplas + " (ECHO found) ELSE (ECHO not found)");

            retornar = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");
            process.WaitForExit(); // espera o cmd.exe terminar

            txtRetorno.Text = retornar;
        }
    }
}
```

Mas sua texto de Retorno é Sempre:

```
Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.16299.248]
```

O utilizar do comando ReadToEnd ao inves do ReadLine:

```
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"g++ -o Source Source.cpp");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"IF EXIST " + aspasDuplas + "Source.exe" + aspasDuplas + " (ECHO found) ELSE (ECHO not found)");            
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"exit");

retornar = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit(); // espera o cmd.exe terminar

txtRetorno.Text = retornar;
```

Mas o seu retorno é toda a escrita do CMD:

```
Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.16299.248]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug>cd C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ConsoleApplication1\\ConsoleApplication1

C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1>g++ -o Source Source.cpp

C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1>IF EXIST "Source.exe" (ECHO found) ELSE (ECHO not found)
not found

C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1>exit
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar a obter apenas o retorno do IF (found ou not found).
Agradeço desde já os que ajudarem.

Comment: Isto é uma das coisas mais inseguras que já vi na vida.

Comment: Porque não fazer um `File.Exists` logo a seguir ao `process.WaitForExit()`? Desde que saiba o caminho do ficheiro, é possível. Contudo, concordo com o @Maniero, é algo que é bastante inseguro de se fazer.

Comment: É que estou fazendo para uso acadêmico, é apenas a parte do código do meu projeto de TCC

Comment: Sendo assim, se remover o ficheiro depois de finalizar o processo, consegue?

Comment: Funcionou aqui, obrigado pela ajuda. Tem como colocar o seu comentário como resposta? E se precisar de algo que eu possa fazer neste post, é só falar.

Comment: Feito :)! Feliz por ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de validar pelo `IF` de o ficheiro existe ou não, pode sempre removê-lo após o término do processo se :

```
// espera o cmd.exe terminar
process.WaitForExit();

string strFile = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Source.exe";

if(File.Exists(strFile)
    File.Delete(strFile);
```

**Código refactorizado:**

```
private void btnExecutar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strPasta = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1";
    string strFicheiro = $"{strPasta}\\Source.exe";
    string retornar = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine($"cd {strPasta}");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("g++ -o Source Source.cpp");

        retornar = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(strFicheiro))
            File.Delete(strFicheiro);

        txtRetorno.Text = retornar;
    }
}
```